# check values of a form's fields with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

i want to check if values of a form is empty or not? i am trying to write my own validator after many validators like jquery.ketchup.0.3.2 failed me (or maybe i failed them )
but i cant make this function to work.

```
function validate() {
    alert("hmmm");
    var inputs = document.forms["register"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var item in inputs) {
        if(item.value.trim() == "")
            alert("nullField");
    }
}
```

would you please tell me what is wrong with the above function?

Comment: _or maybe i failed them_ :)

Comment: which error do you get? where are you applying this function in the HTML? Can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering if it's the `for` loop you used. To loop over a collection (array), use a normal `for` loop, not a `for in`. Maybe this fixes it:

```
function validate() {
    alert("hmmm");
    var inputs = document.forms["register"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].value.trim() == "")
            alert("nullField");
    }
}
```

Note that `.trim()` isn't available in all browsers: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#String.prototype.trim

A jQuery alternative, probably preferred, is to use something like:

```
$('form[name="register"]').find('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$.trim($this.val())) {
        // Left empty
    }
});
```

References:

- `.find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find/
- `.each()`: http://api.jquery.com/each/
- `.trim()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: thnx - it worked :) just for clarification can i change change other attributes of null fileds by calling  inputs[i].someMethod on them?

Comment: @dave Yep, exactly. For example, you could change their border with `inputs[i].style.border = "1px solid #ff0000";`

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use jQuery, then *use jQuery*.

```
validate(){
  var $inputs = $('input', 'form[name="register"]');
  $inputs.each(function(){
    var val = $.trim(this.value);
    if(!val.length){
       // Not valid
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest using jQuery, then use it to do everything the OP had. You left out the `.forms["register"]` part

Comment: @Ian - the OP *suggested* using jQuery when they tagged the question `jQuery`. Have updated with your point though, well caught.

Comment: My only point was that you didn't find the form first, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only javascript:

1st of all make sure that the trim function is defined:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Now for actual function:

```
 function validate() {
    var inputs = document.forms["register"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len ; i++) {
        if(inputs[ i ].value.trim() == ""){
            // Validation failed
        }
    }
    // Validation successful
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I strongly (and I mean STRONGLY) recommend not writing your own validations. Nevertheless, there are a couple of things that are wrong with your code.

1. The for..var..in construct iterates through all the properties of the object. So an object `foo = { bar: '0', baz: '1'}` would iterate through `bar` and `baz` (the properties, not the values). If you want to get the value you need to indicate so by doing 
   `for(var i in foo){ console.log(foo[i]);}`, or in your example: `inputs[item].value`.
2. The `getElementsByTagName` return a `NodeList` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) ). `NodeList`s have additional properties beside the elements in the list.

If you're using jQuery, then you simply do `$("#register input").val()` to get the array of relevant values and you can use the `$.map` function to do something for each value.